# Problem with converting rasters to arrays and adding them to main array, then converting to raster via NumPyArrayToRaster : output is NoData values

Tags: python, raster, arcpy, arcgis-10.1, numpy

I have a process that aims to loop through a list of rasters (testing with only 3)
covert each raster to an array, add the array to an existing 'template' array,  then save the final array back to a raster. I'm not getting errors, but all of the test output is NoData Values. Thanks for your help!

---

```
#import modules
import arcpy, numpy, os, time

#set workspace
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:/GIS/project/test_rasters"

#set snap raster environment
template = "C:/GIS/project/rast01_0"
arcpy.env.snapRaster = template

#define in raster
template_raster = arcpy.Raster(template)

#set output location
outpath = r"C:/GIS/project/out_rasters/rast01_x"

#create an array to serve as the frame for additional arrays.
template_array = arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray(template_raster)
template_array = numpy.float64(template_array)
main_array = template_array * 0

#check array type
print main_array.dtype.name
#start counter
count = 0

#get a list of rasters in workspace
rasters = arcpy.ListRasters()
#for each raster in the workspace
for raster in rasters:
    print "processing: " + raster + " " + time.asctime()
    #make each raster an array, add it to main raster array
    array = arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray(raster)
    main_array = main_array + array
    #count number of raster/arrays added to the main array
    count = count + 1
    print count

#print final count of summed arrays
print count
#save array of sums to raster
part_sum_raster = arcpy.NumPyArrayToRaster(main_array)
part_sum_raster.save(outpath)

print"script completed:  " + time.asctime()
```

Answer (score 1):

Some points need to be clarified:

- Are the rasters single-band or multi-bands ?
- what is the shape of your main_array ?
- What is the final result of your main_array ?

### Example with numpy

Create an array filled with zeros:

```
import numpy as np
main_array= np.zeros((4,5),dtype=np.float64) 
# In your case:
# main_array = np.zeros(template_array.shape, dtype=np.float64)
print main_array
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
main_array.shape
(4, 5)
main_array.size
20
```

Sums of arrays:

```
newarray = np.array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.],
   [ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.],
   [1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.],
   [1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.]])

main_array = main_array + newarray
print main_array
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.],
   [ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.],
   [ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.],
   [ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.]])
main_array = main_array + newarray
print main_array
array([[  2.,   4.,   6.,   8.,  10.],
   [  2.,   4.,   6.,   8.,  10.],
   [  2.,   4.,   6.,   8.,  10.],
   [  2.,   4.,   6.,   8.,  10.]])
 etc.
```

I don't use ArcPy but with GDAL/OGR the result is not NULL:

```
import numpy as np
from osgeo import gdal
ds = gdal.Open('myraster')
array = np.array(ds.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray())
array.shape
(62, 90)
main_array = np.zeros(array.shape, dtype=np.float64)
main_array.shape
(62, 90)
main_array + array == array
array([[ True,  True,  True, ...,  True,  True,  True],
   [ True,  True,  True, ...,  True,  True,  True],
   [ True,  True,  True, ...,  True,  True,  True],
   ..., 
   [ True,  True,  True, ...,  True,  True,  True],
   [ True,  True,  True, ...,  True,  True,  True],
   [ True,  True,  True, ...,  True,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: yes, that looks like what I'd like to happen with my loop - and after printing the arrays within the loop all looks fine until the arcpy.NumPyArrayToRaster() output. single-band, shape = (1059L, 598L), raster of the sum of all arrays.

Comment: That was supposed to be: To answer your questions: single-band, shape = (1059L, 598L), raster of the sum of all arrays. Thanks for looking into this!

Comment: If the resulting array is not empty, so the problem is in  arcpy.NumPyArrayToRaster(main_array)

Comment: okay. i had to address all of the (optional) arguments in the arcpy.NumPyArrayToRaster() and then it worked. thanks @gene for the indirect help with printing the arrays to troubleshoot - i really appreciate it!